# Call function of external javascript file on button click

Tags: javascript, json, function, button, d3.js

I'm building a d3 graph with data from a json-file. The json-file is generated by  executing a javascript-file(`wiki.js`). This file fetches data through an http request and builds the json-file. 
What I want to do is adding a d3 button to my site which executes the `wiki.js` and fetches the new data. And Reload the page of course to display the graph with the new data.

My button looks so far like this:

```
d3.select("#updatebutton").on("click", function(e) {
        updateData();
        window.parent.location = window.parent.location.href; // reload the page
    });
```

The `updateData()` should call the wiki.js file:

```
function updateData() {
try {
     getJSON(); //Name of the function to call in wiki.js file
}
catch (e) {
    alert('Error: ' + e);
}

}
```

Thats the only time I'm using `http`, the `getJSON()` function I'm trying to call in `updateData()`:

```
function getJSON() {
var req = https.get(options, function(response) {
    // handle the response
    var res_data = '';
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        res_data += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
        wikiJSON = JSON.parse(res_data);
        convertJSON(wikiJSON.items);
         //fs.writeFile('../data2.json', res_data, function (err) {
         //if(err) throw err;
         //});
    });
});
req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
req.end();
```

}

If I click the Button on my Page ! get this:

```
Error: TypeError: https is undefined
```

Of course I added my script to my html File with the script-Tag.

How can I solve the problem?

**Update:**

I think it has something to do with the fact that i'm doing an `https.get` in `wiki.js`! Does anyone know about this problem?

Comment: None of the code you've shared attempts to use a variable called `https`, so whatever the problem is, it isn't coming from the code you've shared with us.

Comment: Thats why i am asking this question here! If I execute the `wiki.js` seperately through console, all is fine! But if i call the function of `wiki.js` as above in the button i get the error shown above. @Quentin

Comment: Since you don't call `https` in any of the code you've shared with us, the problem must lie with some code you haven't shared with us. Since we can't see that code, we can't tell you what is wrong with it.

Comment: I added the part where I'm using an `https` request!

Comment: "Thats the only time I'm using http, the getJSON() function I'm trying to call in updateData()" — And where do you define `https`?

Comment: `var https = require('https')` at the beginning of `wiki.js`

Comment: Since the error message says it is undefined, either `require` is returning `undefined` or you're overwriting it later.

Comment: It can't be undefined because if I just run `wiki.js` through the console, it works fine!  And I don't know what you mean with "overwrite it later"?! The code I shared is the only time I am using the `https`

Comment: It must be undefined because your error message explicitly says it is.

Comment: How can it be undefined, if `wiki.js` works just perfect, as it should???

Comment: I don't know. You haven't provided a [complete test case](http://sscce.org/). What I do know is that your error message explicitly says that it is.

Comment: Is this running the JavaScript server-side in node.js or are you running this client-side in the browser?  It looks like you are trying to use the node module `https` in the browser....

Comment: I Think that could be the problem.... the `wiki.js` is called from the server and the d3 graph is on client-side! Do you know a workaround? I just want the d3 graph reloaded with the new json-file on the button-click event! But can't get the json-file updated... @Mark